# Is there a way to capture a pattern, skip a set of random subsequent characters, then continue to capture another pattern using regex?

Tags: regex

I have an example of text like

```
PART I BLABLABLABLALBLA GROUP 2
```

I need to capture `PART I` and `GROUP 2` using the same regex, skipping the set of characters in the middle.

Comment: You should be able to do a capture group for each part you want, and `.*` for the middle.  `/(PART I).*(GROUP 2)/` and then use `$1` and `$2` (or the equivalent in your programming language) to get the matched parts.

Comment: You can't match disjoint texts into a single group within one match operation.

Comment: Thanks @joanis !! The group capture worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a capture group for each part you want, and use `.*` for the middle.

```
/(PART I).*(GROUP 2)/
```

and then use `$1` and `$2` (or the equivalent in your programming language) to get the matched parts.

*(Upgraded my comment to an answer, since OP said it worked.)*